# running MSU not working

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
start /wait wusa.exe %~dp0Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu /quiet /norestart
```

I have a .bat file with the above code.  The file is located in \wds\e$\Shared\DeploymentBuild\Applications\Microsoft WMF 5.0.

The problem is, when I run it, it brings up the "Windows Update Standalone Installer" window and it won't do a silent install.

I have a copy of the same .bat file in my local computer, and it works fine without any issues.  Please help me figure this out.

Thank you,

Tony

Comment: The **/quiet** switch is correct, as seen here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/install).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  I went to the link and I have the correct MSU downloaded.  When I run `Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu /quiet`, it opens the command prompt window and immediately closes.

Comment: My comment was to stop further responders from checking if you were using the correct switch for that specific update, not as an answer to you. However, as you've now stated that running it without WUSA doesn't produce the GUI window then have you checked if the update has installed?

Comment: The update was not installed.

Comment: I have Windows 7 x 64, so I copied and pasted this from Microsoft website  'Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu /quiet.1

Comment: Have you got the pre-requisites? And just to make sure if it's installed run this at a powershell prompt `Get-HotFix | ? {$_.HotFixID -match 'KB3134760'}` no return will confirm it isn't installed. You can also check in your event viewer if there is a reason given for the failure. In Event Viewer, expand **Windows Logs**, and then click **Setup**. Setup events appear in the middle pane. In the **Actions** pane, click **Filter Current Log**. In the **Event sources** list, click to select the **WUSA** check box, and then click **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing your batch file accordingly:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu" (
    Echo= The MSU file isn't here!
    Timeout -1 >Nul
    Exit/B)
wusa.exe "%~dp0Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that, and it install the update silently.  What would happen if I already have WFM 5.0 installed and I try to run the batch file?  I tried that, and it opens and closes after a while, is that normal?

Comment: Yes, Wusa.exe will unpack the msu to a temporary path and perform its checks, then cleanup without installing.